# Fireplace horizontal vent cover is leaking

Tags: fireplace

My fireplace horizontal vent is allowing rain to flood in to my walls. Possibly the homebuilder in 1996 put the cover on wrong. It only covers the sides. There is a screen equivalent to chicken wire covering the top. But this will not stop the rain water from flooding into my walls. In the summer I do put plywood with bungee cords over the top and bottom and attach it to the cover. Due to this being a gas fireplace that will not work for winter when the fireplace is running. Thank you for any help or guidance you can give.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to understand how this works; would you add a picture of the vent, and perhaps a diagram of the flue? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few of our newbies do.

Comment: Daniel Thank You for assisting with  recommendation of adding photo. I’m not seeing the photo on my original post. It does say make pictures smaller. I’m not sure how to do that?

Comment: Hi, Diane. Here's instructions on [adding a picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). If you can't get it to work, just post the URL of an image and someone will be along to edit it in.